# Запись и вывод данных из файла TXT в PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу бота для группы в ВК…

---

Как реализовать функцию при которой при получении сообщения "Подписка" и если его ID не занесён в список он заносит его ID в файл user_id.txt.

---

А при получении сообщения "Отписка" и если его ID занесен в этот список он убирает ID пользователя из данного списка.

---

**PS.** Так же буду благодарен если кто-то скажет как можно перечислять переменные (Например: Привет, привет, хай, ку и т.д.) и он будет понимать что на все эти команды ему нужно отвечать одним сообщением.

---

Заранее спасибо

```
if($user_msg == 'Подписка'){    
        if($user_id == "ID_USER"){
            $v->msgSend("$user_name, ты уже подписан на рассылку!", $user_id, $access_token);           
        } else {
            $v->msgSend("$user_name, спасибо что подписались на рассылку записей. Для отписки используй команду: Отписка.", $user_id, $access_token);
        }
        }

if($user_msg == 'Отписка'){ 
        if($user_id == "ID_USER"){
            $v->msgSend("Вы успешно отписались от «Рассылки постов»!", $user_id, $access_token);            
        } else {
            $v->msgSend("$user_name, вы не можете отписаться от рассылки, так как вы не были подписаны на неё.", $user_id, $access_token);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текстовый файл, возможно, не лучшее хранилище, но для обучения сойдёт.

Первым делом надо придумать формат хранения данных в файле. Это могут быть просто id разделённые символом, который в id точно никогда не встретится. Пусть это будет символ новой строки `\n`, например.

Далее, чтобы искать в уже записанных id, их значения надо прочитать:

```
$idsFile = __DIR__ . '/user_id.txt';

$idsStr = file_get_contents($idsFile);
$ids = array_filter(explode("\n", $idsStr));

var_dump($ids);
```

Соответственно проверить, что id уже есть среди ранее сохранённых id можно с помощью функции `array_search`. Если пользователя ещё нет в списке и Подписка, то добавляем его в массив `$ids`, если Отписка и пользователь есть в массиве то удаляем:

```
$pos = array_search($user_id, $ids);
switch ($user_msg) {
    case 'Подписка':
        if ($pos === false) {
            $ids[] = $user_id;
            $v->msgSend("$user_name, спасибо что подписались на рассылку записей. Для отписки используй команду: Отписка.", $user_id, $access_token);
        } else {
            $v->Send("$user_name, ты уже подписан на рассылку!", $user_id, $access_token);
        }
        break;
    case 'Отписка':
        if ($pos !== false) {
            unset($ids[$pos]);
            $v->msgSend("Вы успешно отписались от «Рассылки постов»!", $user_id, $access_token);
        } else {
            $v->msgSend("$user_name, вы не можете отписаться от рассылки, так как вы не были подписаны на неё.", $user_id, $access_token);
        }
        break;
    case 'привет':
    case 'хай':
    case 'ку':
        //
        break;
}
```

Ну и остаётся сохранить массив `$ids` в файл:

```
file_put_contents($idsFile, implode("\n", $ids));
```

Однако у такого способа много недостатков.

1. Несколько одновременных запросов могут рассогласовать данные в файле. Например, для одного запроса скрипт прочитает файл и добавит id 123, но ещё не успеет записать изменения в файл. А в это время для второго запроса будет прочитан файл (без 123) и в него добавится id 456. Теперь первый обработчик запишет файл с 123, а затем второй с 456. Таким образом в файле не будет записи 123 (её затрёт запись второго обработчика).
2. Чтение и поиск в большом файле могут занимать существенное время.

Эти проблемы хорошо известны и решения для них давно придуманы. Для обеспечения согласованности данных используются блокировки (пока один работает с файлом, остальные ждут). Для ускорения поиска используются индексы (это как алфавитный указатель в книге, позволяет не листать всё сначала, а сразу открыть нужную страницу).

Реализация блокировок и индексов может оказаться достаточно сложной задачей для новичка и достаточно скучной для многоопытного разработчика, но есть готовое решение! Это базы данных. Самым простым вариантом может стать [SQLite](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), для работ с ней надо освоить [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-sqlite.php). Умение работать с базами данных не только поможет вам в задаче с ботом, но и очень пригодится в будущем.

Comment: не могу понять принцип работы case для передачи более одного значения. Перебрав ваш совет и просмотрев статьи пришёл к такому выводу (https://pp.userapi.com/c850324/v850324509/ca7f8/qtWb10xOU8I.jpg) (https://vk.com/wall-93782265_1154) (ругается на ограничение по коду)...

Как в данном случае присвоить дополнительные значения, что бы он например понимал не только Подписаться, но и подписаться, активировать, запустить... Заранее спасибо =)

Comment: Для оператора switch (http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php) после case указывается одно значение, но если указать несколько case подряд, не разделяя их break'ами, то для всех этих case отработает один кусок кода. То же самое можно сделать и с if, там следует использовать логический оператор || (или).

Comment: Вернулся к первоначальному варианту, как вы и предложили. Но появилась проблема, бот отправляет вместо одного ответа 2. То есть на одно новое сообщение "Подписка" он отвечает два раза "Ты уже подписан". А если написать "Подписка" потом через пару секунд "Отписка" то он начнет слать очень много сообщений почти без остановки... Весь код (от и до) с отправкой сообщения тут https://vk.com/wall-93782265_1155
Не могу даже понять из-за чего происходит повторная отправка сообщений...

Comment: @ТимофейКучербаев напишите в телегу ebanin, разберёмся.